# Can you page through aggregation results?

Tags: java, elasticsearch

Is there a way to offset the results of an aggregation like you can query results?

I'm trying to implement pagination based on aggregation results. I have a "content" index that contains the content I'm dealing with. Then I have another "views" index that I use to track the time a piece of content was viewed. I can't precompute the view count since I may only care about views over an arbitrary date range—say all views in november.

My plan was to simply do a terms aggregation on the `contentId` of my views index and have it filtered by the date range I need, then offset the results (using something like from=,size=) to determine that 'page' of contentIds I should be showing. However not being able to offset aggregation results kills that possibility since there could be thousands of pieces of content.

ContentIndex

```
{"contentId": "4", ...}
{"contentId": "5", ...}
```

ViewsIndex

```
{"contentId": "4", date: "2014-11-20T01:01:01"}
{"contentId": "4", date: "2014-11-20T02:02:02"}
{"contentId": "5", date: "2014-11-20T01:01:01"}
{"contentId": "4", date: "2014-11-20T03:03:03"}
```

Comment: Why not design query in such a way that it prefilters based on date?

Comment: I can, and am doing a filter to select then documents I care about. However that could still leave me with a huge number of results even after aggregation. I don't want to possibly get back 30k results for that aggregation. I'd ideally like to get the aggregation results one page at a time—page 1 (from=0,size=10), then page 2 (from=10,size=10) and so on like you could with query results.

Comment: And what would be the pagination criterion? because if you want to browse through content elements, you can also, in theory, filter by them. because otherwise it might be a costly operation on the serverside too (afaik aggregation results are not preserved between calls, and they can even change between calls)

Comment: The criterion would be the count of the aggregation result. So lets say the page size of 1. In my example above, a terms aggregation on "contentId" in the "ViewsIndex" would return "bucket": [{"key": "4", "doc_count": 3}, {"key": "5", "doc_count": 1}], so page=1 would be computing the aggregation, seeing I want contentId 4, and then displaying that. For page=2, I'd do the same with an "from=1" on the aggregation. Not amazing, but would save precomputing everything, and might not be costly with aggregation caching. I don't think this is possible though, I was just checking.

Comment: I see. But I guess in practice, you would be only interested in aggregation results more than a threshold, not in the long tail? (because otherwise there could be better ways to do that than online query) And I guess it's possible to filter aggregation results in that way. E.g. check filter buckets. http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/_filtering_queries_and_aggregations.html